# Extending method by ES6 Proxy works but with TypeError

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, proxy

Implementing a function to extend object method by ES6 Proxy works but with TypeError as below:

```js
const extendMethod = (obj) => (key) => (f) => {
    const handler = {
        get: (target, propKey, receiver) => {
            const targetValue = Reflect.get(target, propKey, receiver);
            return key === propKey
                ? f(target.valueOf())
                : (typeof targetValue === "function")
                    ? (...args) => Object(target.valueOf())[propKey](...args)
                    : targetValue;
        }
    };
    return new Proxy(obj, handler);
};

const a = { x: 5 };
const f = (target) => { console.log(target); };
const a1 = extendMethod(a)("log")(f);
a1.log(); //{x:5}
//TypeError: a1.log is not a function
```

How to modify the code to avoid the error? thanks.

Comment: All right, whatever. I don't ask such a thing.

Comment: @JaromandaX I felt for some reason, to modify the text in the question a bit, so your statement now is invalid.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The script is expecting `a1.log` to evaluate to a *function* because it proceeds to get called as `a1.log();`. But with the line

```
? f(target.valueOf())
```

, the `f` function is run, and the output of calling `f` is then returned to the outside. But the output of `f` is `undefined`, because the (outer) `f` doesn't return anything.

One way to suppress the error would be to return a function that doesn't do anything:

```
? (f(target.valueOf()), () => void 0)
```

```js
const extendMethod = (obj) => (key) => (f) => {
    const handler = {
        get: (target, propKey, receiver) => {
            const targetValue = Reflect.get(target, propKey, receiver);
            return key === propKey
                ? (f(target.valueOf()), () => void 0)
                : (typeof targetValue === "function")
                    ? (...args) => Object(target.valueOf())[propKey](...args)
                    : targetValue;
        }
    };
    return new Proxy(obj, handler);
};

const a = { x: 5 };
const f = (target) => { console.log(target); };
const a1 = extendMethod(a)("log")(f);
a1.log(); //{x:5}
```

Or you might simply *access* the `a1.log` property (calling the function as a side effect) and not invoke it:

```js
const extendMethod = (obj) => (key) => (f) => {
    const handler = {
        get: (target, propKey, receiver) => {
            const targetValue = Reflect.get(target, propKey, receiver);
            return key === propKey
                ? f(target.valueOf())
                : (typeof targetValue === "function")
                    ? (...args) => Object(target.valueOf())[propKey](...args)
                    : targetValue;
        }
    };
    return new Proxy(obj, handler);
};

const a = { x: 5 };
const f = (target) => { console.log(target); };
const a1 = extendMethod(a)("log")(f);
a1.log; //{x:5}
```

If the outer `f` function *did* return a function (that is, if it was a higher-order function), then you would be able to use `a1.log()` normally:

```js
const extendMethod = (obj) => (key) => (f) => {
    const handler = {
        get: (target, propKey, receiver) => {
            const targetValue = Reflect.get(target, propKey, receiver);
            return key === propKey
                ? f(target.valueOf())
                : (typeof targetValue === "function")
                    ? (...args) => Object(target.valueOf())[propKey](...args)
                    : targetValue;
        }
    };
    return new Proxy(obj, handler);
};

const a = { x: 5 };
const f = (target) => {
  console.log(target);
  return arg => {
    console.log('inner fn! ' + arg);
  };
};
const a1 = extendMethod(a)("log")(f);
a1.log('foo');
```

Comment: Obviously, comprehensive super answer! I will investigate thoroughly. Thanks a lot!

Comment: I have another question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51664840/es6-proxy-calling-a-native-method-by-reflect-and-apply I wonder you could provide thought. Thank you.